# Showing user the script is loading

Tags: php, html, mysql, highcharts

I have a problem that I dont know how to solve. Basically, I have a MySQL database, which contains quite a lot of information. 
I then have several PHP sites, which retrieve the data from the database, then do some analysis and calculations and then output it using tables and highcharts graphs.
Now that all works fine, but there is a slight problem. The problem is that when somebody wants to enter the site, it shows "Waiting for.... " in the status bar of the browser and the page displays after about 10-15s. The problem is obviously in the fact that the site first contacts the MySQL database and actually in order to do all the various calculations, there are many calls to the db etc. As such the calcuations work and the only thing I need is to somehow tell the user "something is actually happenning" while the page is being loaded. 
The structure of the PHP site looks like there is the php code at the top, which calculates all the variables and that is followed by the actual HTML, which in some places has the variables echoed.
I tried putting something like:

```
echo "Loading";
flush();
```

and I put that at the very top, but all I got was the same "nothing happening" interval and subsequently the whole page showed, just that I had the "Loading" text at the top, which obviously is not what I wanted, because it showed simultaneously with the rest of the page.

I really would appreciate any ideas how I could solve this. I tried putting the HTML body tag in front of the  PHP at the very top, but that didn't help either and I cannot obviously put the scripts at the very end, because the variables first have to be calculated before they are displayed.

Comment: Flush() doesn't always work like you would expect, as there can be buffers at several levels between your code and the browser. In very broad strokes, I would recommend loading a stub page, then using AJAX to send a message back and start the calculations. That way you can provide the user with something to look at before the expensive operations start.

Comment: you should load your page then load each section via ajax, displaying a loading indicator in the blocks while each section is loading.  it also sounds like you need to optimize your database to take advantage of indexes to speed up your calculations.

Comment: If you don't want to use ajax you can load a page with a loading message first, and then redirect with javascript to the real page, your loading message should stay visible until the real page loads.

Comment: oh that actually sounds quite promising, I will try it

Answer (score 1):

You could display the page first then make an Ajax request for the data ones the site has loaded. In that way you would be able to tell the user that you do stuff in the backgound and display the data when it has loaded.

You can make an Ajax request like this http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.

Comment: Well that was something I was thinking about too, but was sort of trying to avoid, because I dont have much experience with Ajax, it requires a separate page and all I wanted was to just show "Loading" immediately when the page starts to be executed.

Comment: If SEO means anything to you, you shouldn't do that

Comment: Well, that is sort of the way to go. Since PHP runs the complete file and then gives you the output. Just put all you DB/data stuff in another file make the Ajax request onload.

Comment: yes it is, but not the good one, this way, whole data will hide from the eye of google spiders, look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It cant be done using php, php is a server side scripting language that make a HTML as response to a request and sends it to client, and then **dies**, and has no idea what is going on on the client side. It means : 1 request = 1 response .

And it cant echo something **before** loading the page, and after that echo the remained content.

I think you dont need to Ajax call for doing this, a simple HTML and jQuery can help you.

Like this :

```
<body onload='$(".loader").hide();$(".contents").show();'>
<span  class='loader'>Loading</span>
<div style='display:none' class='contents'>
    here is the contents
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: but the problem is that it first does the PHP code and then gets to the BODY and starts displaying, and then it already has all the variables and takes virtually no time, the problem is the time it takes to calculate it before it actually starts displaying anything

Comment: when your php codes are processing, the page will be just `loading...` and when the process is done, it shows the content, trust me, I've tested this [**Here**](http://artsingroup.ir)

Comment: ok, it looks fantastic, but where do I actually put this? Right now my page looks like this:

PHP scripts-BODY-display of the variables-END OF BODY

Comment: ok, tried it but doesnt work, nothing happens for 10-15s and then the content is displayed along with the "here is the contents" string

Comment: put all of html contents in div class=contents and remove `here is the contents...`

Comment: And you can see the html of my site that I mentioned earlier, it can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can asynchronously request your php script. So in your code, you can do

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="path_to_jquery"></script>
    <script>
        $.get(path_to_php_script, function(data) {
             //data here contains stuff from the db.
        });
    </script>
</body>
```